# Wordpress Comments box won't display any input fields

Tags: php, wordpress

I am customising my comments box  but I can't seem to bring in any input fields at all. I can bring in the actual comment box and submit button as I want, but no text fields such as name, email etc.

This is the code I am using in comments.php

```
<?php
$comments_args = array(

    'fields' => apply_filters(
        'comment_form_default_fields', array(
            'author' =>'<p class="comment-form-author">' . '<input id="author" placeholder="Your Name (No Keywords)" name="author" type="text" value="' .
                esc_attr( $commenter['comment_author'] ) . '" size="30"' . $aria_req . ' />'.
                '<label for="author">' . __( 'Your Name' ) . '</label> ' .
                ( $req ? '<span class="required">*</span>' : '' )  .
                '</p>'
                ,
            'email'  => '<p class="comment-form-email">' . '<input id="email" placeholder="your-real-email@example.com" name="email" type="text" value="' . esc_attr(  $commenter['comment_author_email'] ) .
                '" size="30"' . $aria_req . ' />'  .
                '<label for="email">' . __( 'Your Email' ) . '</label> ' .
                ( $req ? '<span class="required">*</span>' : '' ) 
                 .
                '</p>',
        )
    ),

    'comment_notes_after' => '',
    'label_submit'=>'Submit',
    'title_reply' => '',
    'logged_in_as' => '',
    'comment_field' => '<p class="comment-form-comment"><label for="comment"></label><br /><textarea id="comment" name="comment" aria-required="true"></textarea></p>',
);
comment_form($comments_args);
?>
```

What am I missing? I've checked my code against the Wordpress codex and other online tutorials but I can't figure out what the problem is! Is there a corresponding function I need to put in functions.php perhaps?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Many thanks.

Comment: are you sure those are loaded and not hidden due to css ?

Comment: Hi. Yes I inspected the code in the browser and there is definitely nothing there

Comment: have you check backend side admin section to turn off and on comment ...

Comment: Yes comments are enabled. I can bring the comment box in, just no text fields.